# PHP Table Hyperlink

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a table that returns information from mysql.  However, I want to hyperlink each postcode so that when the user clicks on one it will redirect them to an appropriate page.  Here is the code that is in the table:

```
<table style="border:2px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<tr align="center" width="auto">
<td bgcolor="#66CCFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><b>&nbsp;Consultation Date&nbsp;</b></td>
<td bgcolor="#66CCFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><b>&nbsp;Patient Health Care Number&nbsp;</b></td>
<td bgcolor="#66CCFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><b>&nbsp;Location&nbsp;</b></td>
<td bgcolor="#66CCFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><b>&nbsp;Post Code&nbsp;</b></td>
<td bgcolor="#66CCFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><b>&nbsp;Update Record&nbsp;</b></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Consultation Date");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Patient HCN");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"Location");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"Post Code");
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><b><?php echo $f2; ?></b></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><?php echo $f3; ?></td>

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><?php echo "<a href=\"coveragehcp.php?patient= ". $f2 ."\">"?><b><?php echo $f4; ?></b></td>

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><?php echo "<button onclick=\"window.location.href='hcp_form_update.php?patient=$f2'\">"?>Update Record</button></td> <!-- This button redirects the user to the auto-populated form that holds the patients information which allows the user to update it -->
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

However when the user click on the link below I want it to redirect them to another page according to the post code clicked.

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:2px solid black;"><?php echo "<a href=\"coveragehcp.php?patient= ". $f2 ."\">"?><b><?php echo $f4; ?></b></td>
```

Comment: And what is happening when they currently click the link?

Comment: So whats wrong with it??? Do you have any errors?? Whats your question?

Comment: it is redirecting them to the page that has been stated in the link, 'coveragehcp.php'  but i need it to be a different page each time, according to what post code they click on?

Comment: Btw, your HTML is both invalid and suboptimal: get rid of the unsupported attributes like `align` and `bgcolor`, and use CSS classes instead of inline `style` definitions: you'll end up with more maintainable and reusable code, and with a smaller bytesize of the output!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to use the post code as a parameter in the GET, and then use the `$_GET['postcode']` to achieve which page should be presented for the user.

so your PHP code for the link would look something like:

```
<a href=\"coveragehcp.php?patient= ".$f2."&postcode=".$f4."\">"?><b><?php echo $f4; ?></b></td>
```

and on the coveragehcp.php page use this

```
$postcode = $_GET['postcode'];
if(!empty($postcode))
{
    if($postcode == 90210) {
        //Echo beverly hills page
    }
    else {
        //Echo default page
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Post_Code in C:\xampp\htdocs\WorkingWebsite\coveragehcp.php on line 19

Comment: I have the post codes in a database.  How do is assoicate each individual postcode with 1 and 2 etc?

Comment: they are called Post_Codes in the table, so would i write the sql statement : SELECT Post_Code FROM tecnhical_table WHERE postcode = $postcode

Comment: the table is called technical_table and there is a field in the table called Post_Codes where all the postcodes are stored.

Comment: how can I write the code to bring a different page up according to the post code clicked?

Comment: is there no way to write a script where once the post code is clicked in the table the user would be redirected to a page according to the postcode?

Comment: can you provide help for that as I am really stuck... I just need the section which contains the if statements etc. please